# Pausing terminal output

Tags: command-line, terminal, output

I have a command which outputs lots of data (say, strace with lots of syscalls, running for a few minutes).

Is there any option (e.g. command wrapper or something similar) that would allow me to pause the output of the command (just the output on the screen, I don't mind the command running in the background), then unpause it after I take a look on its output?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have three options:

- press <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to stop output, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to resume (this is called XON/XOFF)
- redirect your output to a pager such as `less`, e.g., `strace date | less`
- redirect your output to a file, e.g., `strace -o foo date`, and browse it later.

Comment: Note that stopping the output with either of the two first options here will make the data generating program pause too, while it waits for the output stream to be consumed.

Answer (score 2):

use the | pipe for example

```
ifconfig -a | more
```

this will list until screen is full and one can then scroll further by hitting return / enter.

Comment: I prefer this to `less` because it exits naturally.

Comment: But isn't that more or less the same? ;)